# jsPDF showing only headers but not table data in the downloaded file

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to create a PDF file in Angular 11 using jsPDF library. When the file is downloaded, I only see the headers and not the table rows. Below is my code

```
exportToPDF() {
   let headers = ['loggedInUserId', 'loginId', 'name'];

   let data = [
   {
    'loggedInUserId': 123,
    'loginId': 123,
    'name': 123,
   },
   {
    'loggedInUserId': 123,
    'loginId': 123,
    'name': 123,
   },
   ];

   const doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.table(1, 1, data, headers, { autoSize: true });
   doc.save();
 }
```

Below is the output PDF look like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to make sure to use the `string` type for the value of your cells **always**, even if you have dates  or numbers:

```
 let data = [
   {
    loggedInUserId: "123",
    loginId: "123",
    name: "§Benzara",
   },
   {
    loggedInUserId: "123",
    loginId: "123",
    name: "123",
   }
   ];
```

[**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9grrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)